# .cls edit makes at-sign (@) appear in 'list of tables' and 'list of figures' between chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, documentclass-writing, class-options

I am formatting my thesis and have been using a template for which a custom style file was created. The template had the front matter, such as "list of tables", acknowledgements, etc., listed in the Table of Content. This was to be removed. In this front matter, I also needed to change the headings from "all-cap" to lower case, bold face and left justified. Without any knowledge of style file formatting, I was able to make all these changes in the .cls file but I was left with at-symbols between chapters in the list of tables and list of figures.

[image]

I commented out the two lines listed JAH.

```
\def\listoftables{%
  \@restonecolfalse%
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi%
  \newpage%
  \centerline{\expandafter
%\uppercase %remove JAH
\bfseries%
\expandafter{
\begin{flushleft}%
\listtablename}
\end{flushleft}%
}%
  \bigskip%
  \phantomsection%
%  \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename }%
%%This removes item from TOC. JAH
  % This group overloads \numberline to output ``Table 1.3'' instead of ``1.3''
  \begingroup%
    \let\ORIG@numberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{\ORIG@numberline{\tablename~##1:}}%
    {\ssp\@starttoc{lot}}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi%
  \endgroup %
  }
```

I am using basic trial and error to make these changes and I need some help from someone who understands style file code .cls .sty

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: This is not enough information to resolve the problem.

Comment: Welcome! We need a small, minimal example of code which we can compile to reproduce the problem. All we can say right now is that the problem is pretty much surely not in the code you've posted.

Comment: @Werner Should `\phantomsection` be removed, too?

Comment: It's in general not a good idea to change a class or package file directly

Comment: are you saying the original was `\expandafter\uppercase \bfseries` surely that just gives an error? also `\expandafter{` is applying `\expandafter` to the space token after the `{` but that is not expandable so this does nothing.

Comment: since i find david's comment a little complicated, here's a simpler way of looking at this.  in the code `\centerline{\expandafter\uppercase...`, the `\expandafter` and `\uppercase` go together, so you need to remove both of them.

Comment: @barbarabeeton your rephrasing makes it sound like an edit to working code, but if the comments are to be believed the original could not have been working. in `\expandafter\uppercase\bfseries` the `\expandafter\uppercase` don't  "go together"  they generate an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- but isn't it true that if `\uppercase` is removed, the preceding `\expandafter` should be removed also?  that's what i meant by "go together". (that's not to say that there aren't other errors.)  admittedly, i didn't actually try it to see if it worked.

Comment: @barbarabeeton not necessarily, certainly as it is, the `\expandafter` could be removed or not as they are doing nothing just applying expansion to non-expandable space token,

Answer (score 1):

The `@` are not generated by the code shown, presumably your `\chapter` command is writing something to the `.lot` file. It would be useful to show what is in that file (even more useful would be a reproducible example)

the heading code is

```
  \centerline{\expandafter
%\uppercase %remove JAH
\bfseries%
\expandafter{
\begin{flushleft}%
\listtablename}
\end{flushleft}%
}%
```

Is there any reason not to simply use `\section*{\listtablename}` ?

`\centerline` is not really a latex command it is left over from plain TeX and would not normally produce something that matches other headings in the document. If you do use it, the content must be horizontal mode material (it is like `\hbox`) so can not contain a `flushleft` environment. As it is it generates the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Note that after an error, any output in the pdf is essentially *arbitrary* TeX's error correction is not designed to make sensible typeset output, merely to get itself back into state so that it can process more of the document, mainly for error checking purposes.

The code is probably missing a `%` after the `{` and after `\listtablename}` and the `\expandafter` are not doing anything, the same result would be obtained without them.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I ended up making a quick fix by finding the "@" signs in the `.lot` file and removing them. We are then constrained to only running compile once, but it worked for now. Thanks everyone for the comments.